# having the same function in multiple c source files

Tags: c, gcc

I'm having a hard time finding out why i can't have the same function in several C source files.
I always thought that i can't access functions in another source file as long as they ain't declared in a header file.

**Lets assume i have the following:**

main.c -> includes thread1.h & thread2.h

thread1.h -> declares e.g. void * thread1();

thread1.c -> defines void * thread1(){} and defines void lock(){}

thread2.h -> declares e.g. void * thread2();

thread2.c -> defines void * thread2(){} and defines void lock(){}

**Now gcc tells me i can't do that!**

gcc -pthread -Wall -o executable main.c thread1.c thread2.c

*ERROR: multiple definition of `lock'*

**So my question now is:**
How can I accomplish what i want?

I don't think that this is meant to be impossible. Otherwise all that C source code available within all the many C libraries would need to be unique. (nah would make no sense, or would it?)

So i thought to myself about 3h ago that there must be a solution. That i must be missing something here.

Well I tried googling it ... but somehow my google skills didn't help me this time.
Is there really no way of doing this? Or am I just to stupid to search for it?

*Thanks in advance,*

*leep*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need that function `lock()` to be `static`.

```
static void lock() {..}
```

The reason is that functions with `static` are not visible outside of the "translation unit".  In other (probably wrong) words, the static functions are *private* to the *.c file. Hence they dont cause linking errors in the linking stage, as you are currently having.

Comment: To add on this. _static_ means that a function is not _exported_. It does not have a name outside that source file, so it won't collide.

Comment: thanks, you are my hero today :D perfect!
wonder why google didn't find me that one ...

Comment: is this still valid if i call that now static lock from within a function that gets exported? (e.g. thread1(){ lock(); } in my example in the question?) Or could that cause other problems?

Comment: `static` means that it is not visible to any other *.c file. But within `thread1.c` its still visible, and you can invoke it. So it wont cause any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare lock as `static void lock(){}`.

Otherwise the function name will be visible all over the program and you'll get a name collision (although you still won't be able to call it without a function prototype).